# how to configure, install and run Android in xen as domU as second guest OS (already ubuntu is running domU as one of guest OS)

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, xen, hypervisor

For exynos 5250,i have installed xen on arm cortex-A15 platform.
1).I have done ubuntu as domU(guest OS ) and i want to run android as second guest OS.
2)*Can anyone help me on how to configure,where i have to configure in Android layers.*

Comment: Could you please post the answer, if you successfully completedmit?